# Golang http.Get too many redirects

Tags: http, go, download

I'm trying to download a file from the web. It should be a simple processes. One that I've alredy done before. But, this particular link (a 135 kB zip file) gives me an error message: `Get "http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip": stopped after 10 redirect`. If I copy the link into the browser the file is downloaded without any issues, but when using the code below, the error pops up.

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    link := "http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip"
    resp, err := http.Get(link)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Create the file
    out, err := os.Create("ms.zip")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer out.Close()

    // Write the body to file
    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why does this happens and how to get around it?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating this url I see that it sets cookie 
`Set-Cookie: security=true; path=/`

You can set cookie manually, or implement CookieJar

```
    c := http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", link, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{Name: "security", Value: "true", Path: "/"})

    resp, err := c.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is totally fine, but you'll often find this issue is more related to the source you're trying to download a file from, itself, rather than Go.

You would have had the same issue with other tools/languages, because the host you are trying to reach, keeps redirecting you because of an invalid **'User-Agent'** header property. This is often the case when you want to allow your files to be downloadable only from 'browsers', rather than crawls, automated scripts etc.

With Go, you can add the header property with `req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "<some-user-agent-value>")`, before sending the request. You'd create an instance of `request` set the header, and execute it with a `http.Client{}` and `client.Do(req)`.

Eg:

```
    link := "http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", link, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0") // Doesn't even have to be a full
                                                // proper user agent string
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

You can read more in the [Go's http pkg docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/), it states that:

> "For control over HTTP client headers, redirect policy, and other
>   settings, create a Client..."

Here's also the [http.reqeust](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go) and [http.client](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go) docs.

More about this ingeneral you can find in e.g. [Mozilla's HTTP docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP), as well as many other great docs and resources out there.

*Btw. the zip archive you're trying to download seems like invalid. :-)*